# Remove decimal in JavaScript for automatically result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a calculator with JavaScript for calculate result automatically. It's work but I can't remove decimal.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".input").keyup(function() {
    var val1 = +$(".value1").val();
    var val2 = +$(".value2").val();
    var val3 = +$(".value3").val();
    var val4 = +$(".value4").val();
    var val5 = (".result");
    var decval5 = (val5);
    $(decval5).val(((((val1 / 8) + val2) / 16) + val3) * val4);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;background:#fff;">
  <div style="padding:10px 0px 10px 10px;">
    <div style="font-size:20px;"></div>
    <br>
    <center>
      input1
      <input type="text" class="input value3">input2
      <input type="text" class="input value2"> input3
      <input type="text" class="input value1"> input4
      <input type="text" class="input value4"> &nbsp;=&nbsp; result
      <input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="result">
    </center>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: not sure what your question is can you clarify please.

Comment: just curious what you are using this to calculate

Comment: I just use javascript and it's work now :) thz a lot bro :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Math.round()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".input").keyup(function() {
    var val1 = +$(".value1").val();
    var val2 = +$(".value2").val();
    var val3 = +$(".value3").val();
    var val4 = +$(".value4").val();
    var val5 = (".result");
    var decval5 = (val5);
    $(decval5).val(Math.round(((((val1 / 8) + val2) / 16) + val3) * val4));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;background:#fff;">
  <div style="padding:10px 0px 10px 10px;">
    <div style="font-size:20px;"></div>
    <br>
    <center>
      input1
      <input type="text" class="input value3">input2
      <input type="text" class="input value2"> input3
      <input type="text" class="input value1"> input4
      <input type="text" class="input value4"> &nbsp;=&nbsp; result
      <input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="result">
    </center>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes bro I'm waiting to do that :D

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
$(decval5).val(Math.round(((((val1 / 8) + val2) / 16) + val3) * val4));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can round the answer up or down or just truncate it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".input").keyup(function() {
    var val1 = +$(".value1").val();
    var val2 = +$(".value2").val();
    var val3 = +$(".value3").val();
    var val4 = +$(".value4").val();
    var val5 = (".result");
    var decval5 = (val5);
    $(decval5).val(((((val1 / 8) + val2) / 16) + val3) * val4);
    
   // Round Up:
   console.log(Math.ceil(parseFloat($(decval5).val())));
    
   // Round Down:
   console.log(Math.floor(parseFloat($(decval5).val())));    
    
   // Truncate:
   console.log(parseFloat($(decval5).val()).toFixed(0));  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;background:#fff;">
  <div style="padding:10px 0px 10px 10px;">
    <div style="font-size:20px;"></div>
    <br>
    <center>
      input1
      <input type="text" class="input value3">input2
      <input type="text" class="input value2"> input3
      <input type="text" class="input value1"> input4
      <input type="text" class="input value4"> &nbsp;=&nbsp; result
      <input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="result">
    </center>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: @MyatZuckerberg No problem. Don't forget to upvote and mark as the answer.

Comment: Yes bro I'm waiting to do that :D